# Oracle to Cassandra real-time replication

Tags: oracle, cassandra, real-time

We have an Oracle Database that resides tables. We would like to implement a new project as I mentioned in title; Oracle to Cassandra real-time replication.

But this new Cassandra environment would be as a reporting service. From the application (in-house), datas is inserted to Oracle production environment. Then our custom service (or what ever) will read delta and insert to Cassandra (this would be like Goldengate may be).

Briefly, does the Cassandra will answer our needs for this scenario?

In our case, we have 20 oracle DBs in different locations (these 20 dbs has similar implementation) 1 central report DB that is daily refresh from these 20 DBs. We use "outdated" snapshot technology, every night our central single report DB (REPORTDB) with fast refresh option, we gather the daily delta from these 20 dbs within oracle ss. we need a structure that reads data from 20 dbs and real-time injection to new cassandra database just like REPORDB

Answer (score 2):

These days you can run spark jobs on Cassandra, thanks to Datastax so yes it can be used as a reporting tool. It's best utilized as a key value store if your number of writes are high compared to your reads.

Reading delta is not real time so you should try using Oracle's AQs. I've been doing real time replication of Oracle to Cassandra using Oracle's AQ and Apache Storm for almost 4 years now and it's running flawlessly.

Comment: Hello @Anshul , In our case, we have 20 oracle DBs in different locations (these 20 dbs has similar implementation) 1 central report DB that is daily refresh from these 20 DBs. We use "outdated" snapshot technology, every night our central single report DB (REPORTDB) with fast refresh option, we gather the daily delta from these 20 dbs within oracle ss. we need a structure that reads data from 20 dbs and real-time injection to new cassandra database just like REPORDB.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand this Oracle/Cassandra architecture running alongside.

Either Oracle suits your needs then you should stick with it. Or it doesn't and you need scalability/high availability then switch to Cassandra.

Can you elaborate on the reasons that make you choose Cassandra for the reporting service ?

Comment: I wrote our case comment to Anshul answer, thank you in advance

Comment: Enterprise environments can have all sorts of databases talking to each other and it's almost unheard of to change the database architecture if the application is not greenfield.